# How to fill an LIST C#

Tags: c#

I have the following classes and I need to fill myDATA.Add(......)

```
public class AAClass
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public DateTime value { get; set; }
}

public class BBClass
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class MyRootClass
{
    public List<AAClass> AA { get; set; } 
    public List<BBClass> BB { get; set; }    
}

void Main()
{
    var myData = new List<MyRootClass>();
    myData.Add(new MyRootClass() { AA = new AAClass { ts = 1636862399574, value = "2021-11-14 00:57:25.04998"  }});
    myData.Add(new MyRootClass() { AA = new AAClass { ts = 1636862398995, value = "2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979"  }});
    myData.Add(new MyRootClass() { BB = new BBClass { ts = 1636862399574, value = "16183.8"  }});
    myData.Add(new MyRootClass() { BB = new BBClass { ts = 1636862398995, value = "16250.8"  }});
}
```

My code in void Main () returns an error because I am not sure how to add the data.

I have the error in this line:

```
myData.Add(new MyRootClass() { ...........  });
```

My purpose is to be able to fill the list to finally obtain this:

```
{
  "AA": [
    {
      "ts": 1636862399574,
      "value": "2021-11-14 00:57:25.049983"
    },
    {
      "ts": 1636862398995,
      "value": "2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979"
    }
  ],
  "BB": [
    {
      "ts": 1636862399574,
      "value": "16183.8"
    },
    {
      "ts": 1636862398995,
      "value": "16250.8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have two opening brackets "{" and only one closing bracket "}" in your line. Are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: AA property is defined as List<AAClass>, but you are trying to init it as a new valueClass.

Comment: I have already corrected the typing errors!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few issue, you are initialing it wrong, also you cant use the word `value` as a variable name as it is a reversed keyword in C#

[Play with it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7sG8S)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
public class AAClass
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public DateTime _value { get; set; }
}

public class BBClass
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string _value { get; set; }
}

public class MyRootClass
{
    public List<AAClass> AA { get; set; } 
    public List<BBClass> BB { get; set; }    
}
    public static void Main()
{
        var myData = new List<MyRootClass>();
    
        myData.Add(new MyRootClass());
        myData[0].AA = new List<AAClass>();
        myData[0].AA.Add(new AAClass() { ts = 1636862399574, _value = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-14 00:57:25.04998")  });
        
        myData.Add(new MyRootClass());
        myData[1].AA = new List<AAClass>();
        myData[1].AA.Add(new AAClass() { ts = 1636862398995, _value = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979")  });
        
        myData.Add(new MyRootClass());
        myData[2].BB = new List<BBClass>();
        myData[2].BB.Add(new BBClass() { ts = 1636862399574, _value = "16183.8" });

        myData.Add(new MyRootClass());
        myData[3].BB = new List<BBClass>();
        myData[3].BB.Add(new BBClass() { ts = 1636862398995, _value = "16250.8" });
}
}
```

#### However as you want a certian result, I believe you actually want code that looks like this

[Play with it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFgJX9)

```
public static void Main()
{
        var myData = new MyRootClass();

        myData.AA = new List<AAClass>();
        myData.BB = new List<BBClass>();
        
        myData.AA.Add(new AAClass() { ts = 1636862399574, _value = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-14 00:57:25.04998")  });
        myData.AA.Add(new AAClass() { ts = 1636862398995, _value = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979")  });        
        myData.BB.Add(new BBClass() { ts = 1636862399574, _value = "16183.8" });
        myData.BB.Add(new BBClass() { ts = 1636862398995, _value = "16250.8" });
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: Value is not a reserved word in C#.  It is a contextual keyword to setter and getter of properties but can be used elsewhere, such as in @Blindy's answer.

Comment: @Dean That's what I needed. For me it works 100%. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that I'm not impressed by the amount of code you can write for no reason, but if all you want is to generate the JSON you pasted in your question, then this is more than enough:

```
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
    {
        AA = new[]
        {
            new { ts = 1636862399574, value = "2021-11-14 00:57:25.049983" },
            new { ts = 1636862398995, value = "2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979" },
        },
        BB = new[]
        {
            new { ts = 1636862399574, value = "16183.8" },
            new { ts = 1636862398995, value = "16250.8" }
        }
    });
```

Comment: value cant be used as a variable.

Comment: You are mistaking, but thanks for repeating that yet again.

Comment: @Blindy Your example was of great help, for me it works 100%.